# Unable to use css classes in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, codepen

I'm using a codepen frontend template in my Ruby on Rails project so now i'm unable to connect my css file with my login.html.erb, like in this code, for submit button i want to use the "submit" class which i have styled in my css file. Also the final rendered page i not stylised which brought me to the conclusion that css file is not getting connected. Please be precise on your answer as I'm a complete beginner as this is my first RoR project.
[Codepen Template](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQxdXZ#anon-signup)
 and [My Rails Project](https://github.com/aashish-ak/QAengine) and My [login.html.erb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LawZAwfUJUUUduNjA0VTFscUk) file.

```
<h2>Welcome back,</h2>
 <%= form_tag("/create_session", method: :get) do %>
      Username :<%= text_field_tag(:username) %><br>
      Password :<%= password_field_tag(:password) %><br>
    <%= submit_tag(:Login), class => "submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

I'm getting the following error:-

```
app/views/sessions/login.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to declare a css class for the `submit_tag` you can do it using `:class => "class_name"`, or better if it would be like `class: "class_name"`.

So you could try with:

```
<%= submit_tag(:Login), :class => "submit" %>
<%= submit_tag 'Login', class: "submit" %> <!-- recommended way -->
```

Comment: That worked @Sebastian but what about the css connection, the page is not getting the desired look as the css file is not getting connected to the login page. [Expectation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LawZAwfUJUWjdyQ1h5d3p1clU) vs [Reality](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LawZAwfUJURXdxMm9OcVRiVG8) My [login.html.erb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LawZAwfUJUUUduNjA0VTFscUk) file.

Comment: I've cloned the repo, but doesn't have such changes, could you update it and to see what's missing?

Comment: Now clone again @Sebastian, i've made some changes and committed again as 'Frontend Incomplete'